Nginx fails to load CSS and PNG files
I'm trying to create a basic PHP web application. I want to host it on nginx. It works fine on my host machine, but when I try to move it to docker it fails to load the CSS and PNG files, even tho PDF files download normally (I have a button that downloads an example PDF). When I use the "try_files $uri $uri/ =404;" "in the location /" block I see that in the network page I get 404 on all of the files I request (when I use try_files $uri $uri/ /krzys-site.php?$query_string; I get "the stylesheet http:// 127.20.0.2/css/krzys_site.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.").
Here is my code:
docker-compose.yaml
services:
  #nginx
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      #- ./PHP/Krzys-App:/var/www/html/Krzys-App
    networks:
      - bridge_net
      - ipvlan_net
        #ipv4_address: 192.168.1.11
  #php
  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./PHP/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./PHP/Krzys-App:/var/www/html/Krzys-App
    networks:
      #- bridge_net
      ipvlan_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.20
  #mysql
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_DATABASE: KrzysiuApp
    networks:
#      - bridge_net
      ipvlan_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.30

volumes:
  mysqldata:

networks:
  ipvlan_net:
    external: true
    name: ipvlan_net
  bridge_net:
    driver: bridge

nginx configuration
nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/Krzys-App;
    index krzys-site.php;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /krzys-site.php?$query_string;
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index krzys-site.php;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|webp|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$ {
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /krzys-site.php?$query_string;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        expires 30d;
    add_header Content-Type text/css;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

Head of my PHP file.
PHP/Krzys-App/krzys-site.php
`<?php
    include_once 'Includes/mysql_connection.php';
    require_once "Includes/login_view.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/krzys_site.css">
    <title> Krzys-App </title>
</head>`

I tried charset utf-8, include mime.types, changing the owner of all the files, connecting every container to the bridge network... basically everything i found on the internet.

Did you make sure that files are actually included in the image? Also make sure that nginx will have permission to read these files.

The mime type error you are getting is most probably your server serving /krzys-site.php?$query_string (fallback) with status 200 as fallback response (it is html file) to css/krzys_site.css, and browser understands that this is not .css file thus MIME type error

Also what i can notice is you are using relative path to import your css, I am quite sure you want to use absolute path, so href="/css/krzys_site.css" instead of href="css/krzys_site.css"

You're using an unmodified Nginx image and the only file you map into it is the config file. So it doesn't have access to your CSS and PNG files. It looks like you've had a volume mapping on /var/www/html/Krzys-App at one point, but it's commented out in the compose file.

@AssGoblin69 Yes, files do get copied into containers properly. I changed the owner and permission, but it didn't work.

@HansKilian Yes, at one point, I mapped those files into my Nginx container. When I copied every file and played with the code a little it did serve PNG and CSS files, but they were on the Nginx container, not the PHP container (where I wanted them to be).  How can I give access to those files other than changing permissions to 777 in the PHP container?

Then you need to change the Nginx config rules so it'll pass the requests for CSS and PNG files on to the PHP container. Like you do with PHP files. But that leads to the question of why you have the Nginx container at all, if all requests are handled by the PHP container?

@HansKilian All requests are handled by the Nginx container, not the PHP container (at least I think... I'm new to this). I enter the IP of the Nginx container and get served PHP content. I posted my whole code regarding the Nginx config and Docker config, how should I change it, so that the Nginx is handling the requests (if it isn't already)? Thank you for your input, I really appreciate it.

Yes, but it seems that all the Nginx container does is pass the requests on to the PHP container. So it doesn't add anything and you could just send the requests directly to the PHP container.

@HansKilian So if I understand correctly Nginx is a proxy that manages requests. I tried to get my head around the "passing the requests on to the PHP container", but I don't fully understand what you meant. Could you explain the correct implementation in more detail or send me a tutorial/explanation on a forum? Also, am I not passing CSS/PNG requests? From what I know PHP and CSS are handled similarly in my code. I have got to say I'm really lost here.

You have 4 location: blocks in your nginx config file. #2 is for PHP files and #3 is for (among other things) CSS files. The PHP block passes any requests on to the PHP container because of the fastcgi_pass statement. The CSS block looks for the file inside the Nginx container. If you want your CSS files in the PHP container, you'd change the CSS block to also pass requests on to the PHP container. And then Nginx doesn't really do anything anymore, since all requests will be passed on. So you no longer need the Nginx container.

@HansKilian I've copied over fastcgi_pass to the CSS block, but it still doesn't work. Thank you again for the fast response and time taken. I'm very new to the Nginx. This is my code:
location ~* .(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|webp|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$ {         fastcgi_pass app:9000;         fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method; add_header Content-Type text/css;         add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform"; include fastcgi_params;         try_files $uri $uri/ =404; } The code is unreadable, but TLDR I've added fastcgi_pass and fastcgi_param REQUEST METHOD

It's a shot in the dark, but perhaps it's to do with relative path of your css. Try to use absolute path instead and let me know if anything changes.
Change
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/krzys_site.css">

to
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/krzys_site.css">


No, sorry, it still doesn't work sadly.
